# how to convert string of date format 'dd/MM/yyyy' to type date only using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui-angular2

I have tried below code to get the date from 'yyyy-mm-dd' format to 'dd/MM/yyyy'.
But when i check the typeof() the result, it is of type string.
Is there some way to convert it to only date.

```
let result;
const timestamp = Date.parse(myStringDate)
if (isNaN(timestamp) === false) {
  const newdate = new Date(myStringDate);
 result = `${newdate.getDate()}/${newdate.getMonth()+1}/${newdate.getFullYear()}`
  return result;
} else {
  return myStringDate;
}
```

Comment: what is the value of mystringdate

Comment: mystringdate will have date format like '2017-12-10'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
const [year, month, day]: string[] = myStringDate.split('-');
const awesomeDate = `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
```

If you wan't to calculate something with the date, I'd look for a properly formatted date to work with `moment.js`, which will allow any format you want.